# Entity Framework concurrency refresh and update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, refresh, updates

I have written a .NET + EF application. Everything works fine on a single thread. On multiple threads - it's another story.

In my EF object I have an integer counter. This property is marked as "Concurrency Mode = Fixed". Basically, what I'm trying to do is **update this counter on several threads**.
Like this operation:

```
this.MyCounter -= 1;
```

Because it's concurrency mode has been changed to "Fixed", when I'm tring to update a property that's already change - an `OptimisticConcurrencyException` is thrown.

In order to solve this concurrency problems, I'm using this code:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        this.UsageAmount -= 1; // Change the local EF object value and call SaveChanges().
        break;
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
    {
        Logger.Output(LoggerLevel.Trace, this, "concurrency conflict detected.");
        EntityContainer.Instance.Entities.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, this.InnerObject);
    }
}
```

The result of this code is an infinite (or maybe its just looks like) loop. Every call of `this.UsageAmount -= 1` throw an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`, which causes the loop to run again.

My `EntityContainer.Instance.Entities` is a singleton class that provides an EF context PER THREAD. This means that every thread has a unique context. The code:

```
public sealed class EntityContainer
    {
        #region Singlethon Implemantation
        private static Dictionary<Thread, EntityContainer> _instance = new Dictionary<Thread,EntityContainer> ();
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();
        public static EntityContainer Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_instance.ContainsKey(Thread.CurrentThread))
                {
                    lock (syncRoot)
                    {
                        if (!_instance.ContainsKey(Thread.CurrentThread))
                            _instance.Add(Thread.CurrentThread, new EntityContainer());
                    }
                }
                return _instance[Thread.CurrentThread];
            }
        }
        private EntityContainer()
        {
            Entities = new anticopyEntities2();
        }
        #endregion

        anticopyEntities2 _entities;
        public anticopyEntities2 Entities
        {
            get
            {
                //return new anticopyEntities2();
                return _entities;
            }
            private set
            {
                _entities = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW, after calling the `Entities.Refresh` methods - it looks like it's working (object state is Unchanged and the propery value is exactly what exists in the database).

How can I solve this concurrency problem?

Comment: Could you post the code for the singleton class you mentioned `EntityContainer.Instance.Entities`? - Just the part where you're providing "an EF context per thread."

Comment: EntityContainer.Instance.Entities code is inserted into the post.

Comment: When you say *every* call throws, could this be down to some threads being prevented from making updates because they get beaten to the database every time? Is the value in the DB actually changing?

Comment: This code is working ok for a while... but, sometimes it's enter "problems mode" which throw OptimisticConcurrencyException for each tring to change the value. I'm dont know why it's enter this mode or when. Looks for me pretty random. When i'm checked if there are another thread that tring to do the same operation - It's seems to me that no another thread is currenly running (but, not guarantee about this).

Comment: So when it hits "problem mode", the DB value doesn't change *at all*, and it looks like *every single* thread is throwing *every time*? Just to be clear, if the DB value is still changing, then somewhere, somehow, there's a thread which is still succeeding in making updates?

Comment: On "problem mode" - the db value doesnt change at all. I'm see the table drictly via MS Managment Studio, and the value is not changed. So, I'm assume that there arn't background threads that updating this value successfuly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in some code that I wrote for a multi-instance azure webrole by using a semaphore that I save in my database.  Here's the code I use to get the semaphore.  I had to add in some extra code to handle the race condition that happens between my competing instances.  I also add in a time release in case my semaphore gets stuck locked because of some error.

```
        var semaphore = SemaphoreRepository.FetchMySemaphore(myContext);
        var past = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1);

        //check lock, break if in use.  Ignor if the lock is stale.
        if (semaphore == null || (semaphore.InUse && (semaphore.ModifiedDate.HasValue && semaphore.ModifiedDate > past)))
        {
            return;
        }

        //Update semaphore to hold lock
        try
        {
            semaphore.InUse = true;
            semaphore.OverrideAuditing = true;
            semaphore.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            myContext.Entry(semaphore).State = EntityState.Modified;
            myContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            //concurrency exception handeling another thread beat us in the race.  exit
            return;
        }
        catch (DBConcurrencyException)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Do work here ...
```

My semaphore model looks like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Semaphore : MyEntityBase //contains audit properties
{

    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public bool InUse { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```